# Mask information in CSV file using sha256 in Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, hash, mask, sha256

I have a CSV file that contains `Name`, `Address`, and `Password`. I want to mask `Address` and `password` using sha256 in Python.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import hashlib
import csv

def hash_pw(input_file_name, output_file_name): 
    hash_lookup = {} 

    with open(input_file_name, newline='') as f_input, open(output_file_name, 'w', newline='') as f_output: 
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output) 

        for user, hash in csv_input: 
            csv_output.writerow([user, hash_lookup[hash]]) 

hash_pw('input.csv', 'output.csv')
```

I don't know how to specify to mask only address and password columns?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: import hashlib
import csv

def hash_pw(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    
    hash_lookup = {}


    with open(input_file_name, newline='') as f_input, open(output_file_name, 'w', newline='') as f_output:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

        for user, hash in csv_input:
            csv_output.writerow([user, hash_lookup[hash]])

hash_pw('input.csv', 'output.csv')

Comment: i dont know how to specify to mask only address and password column.

Comment: Please, never ever add code in comments, edit your question and add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as your `input.csv` file contains three items, your loop needs to read three items. You could then have a function that takes text and returns the hashed values. You can then use this function to hash the address and password fields.

I suggest returning the hex digest so that it can be easily written to your `output.csv` file:

```
import hashlib
import csv

def hash(text):
    return hashlib.sha256(text.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()


def hash_file(input_file_name, output_file_name): 
    hash_lookup = {} 

    with open(input_file_name, newline='') as f_input, open(output_file_name, 'w', newline='') as f_output: 
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output) 
        csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))    # Copy the header row to the output

        for user, address, password in csv_input: 
            csv_output.writerow([user, hash(address), hash(password)]) 

hash_file('input.csv', 'output.csv')
```

So if your `input.csv` contained the following:

```
Name,Address,Password
Fred,1 Rock Close,MyPassword
Wilma,1 Rock Close,Password1234
```

The `output.csv` would then look like:

```
Name,Address,Password
Fred,fc3b252cf37b3d247a38068a5f58cc8fc6b9ea3e938831c6d90f8eb9e923d782,dc1e7c03e162397b355b6f1c895dfdf3790d98c10b920c55e91272b8eecada2a
Wilma,fc3b252cf37b3d247a38068a5f58cc8fc6b9ea3e938831c6d90f8eb9e923d782,a0f3285b07c26c0dcd2191447f391170d06035e8d57e31a048ba87074f3a9a15
```

As you can see, the values for the address are the same. The header row can be copied first before hashing the remaining rows.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin. It hashes the columns. one more question. Is there a way that it doesn't hash the column titles? for example, leave the word 'password' but hash the values of password.

Comment: If your file has headers, then you just need to copy it over first before processing the remainder of the file. I have updated the script to show you how.